# How to merge a color multiband raster to a singleband color raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, multi-band

**Background:**

At Arc Desktop 10.6.1, I have an aerial photo tif image: 4-band (RGBA), 16-bit, unsigned integer.  When displayed, it shows as natural-color.  Here's a screen snip of just a small portion of the image:

[image]

**Problem:**

The image's file size - 14 GB(!) - is too great.  I suspect the large file size results from its 3-inch pixel resolution and 4 bands.

I would like to reduce the image's file size, while a) keeping the same pixel dimensions, and b) retaining *some degree* of the original color.  In other words, I'm willing to accept a limited range of colors in the output if I can keep the 3-inch pixel size.  Given the 3-inch constraint, my only option appears to be to reduce the number of bands to one.

If a single-band output could be achieved with 16-bit color, its resulting 65,536 colors just might be enough.  I need to answer that question, but have not yet been able to output such a single-band color image.

This screen snip shows conceptually what I would like to accomplish in Arc:

[image]
[Source](http://www.avenza.com/resources/blog/2010/06/03/creating-false-color-composite-image-geographic-imager-adobe-photoshop/)

Although this example utilized satellite imagery, and outputs to a false-color image, it shows my train of thought: reduce file size by merging the RGB bands into a single output band containing some degree of color.

**Efforts to date:**

I've been able to create a single-band **grey** image using this flow:

1. Using the Arcmap > Windows > Image Analysis tool, **Clip** the source image
2. In the ensuing raster Layer Properties > Functions > R-click > Insert Function > Grayscale Function > apply equal weights to R, G, and B.

The output image is now single-band, 16-bit, and it's file size is reduced from 14 GB to 3 GB.  Good news, but unfortunately it's not color...

I've tried other functions in addition to Grayscale, but to no avail.

How can I merge the multiple bands into a single color band, using Arc?

Comment: Have you considered converting it to an 8-bit, 4-band image? That will still give you 256 color levels per band, and also provide a significant size reduction.

Comment: @Bjorn D'Oh!  Why didn't I think of that!  You have a great idea.  I used Arc Raster Copy, and the output file size is cut in half, to 7 GB. The colors looked great.  I also tried a 4-bit output, and its file size was cut in half again to 3.5 GB, but the colors started to look a little dodgy.  But I'm still hoping for a single-band, 16-bit color solution, which - if my math is correct - should result in 3.5 GB with 65K color.

Comment: 4-bits will only offer 16 color levels/band; which would be the same as your single-band, 16-bit solution. If you don't need the extra band, stripping it out would reduce the size by another 25%.

Comment: Trying to put 3 bands in a 16-bit space would only allow 5 bits/band (32 color levels), only slightly better than your 4-bit attempt. And it would require special compress/decompress routines before any programs could read it.

Comment: PS there's no such thing as a single band colour raster (excluding colour tables). You need one band per colour channel. Look into lossy compressed (i.e jpeg) 8bit per channel formats.

Comment: Ahah!  Thanks for your comment - it was the key to my enlightenment!  I had been misled by the "merge channel" screen snip in my OP.  Upon further examination, their single output (labeled "merge channel") actually contained 3 bands, not one, as the graphic led me to believe.  Now I need to learn about this mysterious thing you call "colour tables"...  Thanks again to you and @Bjorn.